# How to use lazily instantiated property within another lazy instantiation

Tags: ios, swift, lazy-initialization

Xcode does not see my lazily instantiated property `components` within lazy instantiation of `weekdayLetters`. How can I resolve this?

`DaysViewController.Type does not have a member named 'components'`

```
lazy var weekdayLetters: [String] = {
    for index in 0...Constants.kNumberOfWeekdays - 1 {
        components.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday + index
        ...
    }
    return ...
    }()

lazy var components: NSDateComponents = {
    let comps = NSDateComponents()
    comps.weekOfYear = 1
    return comps
    }()

lazy var calendar: NSCalendar = {
    return NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    }()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit `self.` solves your problem:

```
self.components.weekday = self.calendar.firstWeekday + index
^^^^^                     ^^^^^
```

As far as I know, There is no document about this.